# Unable to verify the challenge parameter for Slack API

Tags: google-apps-script, slack

I'm new to this and trying to figure out the basics. I want to use google apps script to receive requests from slack and send back information from a spreadsheet.

I am stuck at this step. [EventsAPI - URL Verification](https://api.slack.com/events-api#url_verification). My approach was to have a doPost() function that returns the challenge. After I was able to confirm slack could connect to the app I would be able to build it out to send the required information from the spreadsheet.

```
function doPost(e){

return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).challenge);

}
```

I expect the challenge to be successfully returned and the URL verified.

The error I receive in Slack is `Request URL Your URL didn't respond with the value of the challenge parameter.`

Comment: Please clarify your approach.

Comment: Can you confirm whether the event object ``e`` of ``doPost(e)`` has  the correct value, when Web Apps was accessed?